# MEAN STACK- app-root in index.html not getting rendered

Tags: mean-stack

Working on a MEAN Stack Application. **app-root in index.html not getting rendered. index.html is loading but not the html defined inline in template**. Created the REST API & successfully obtaining data from mongodb. Searched similar threads on stackoverflow but not the same issue. Please help.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var port = 3000;
var app = express();
var api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '../dist')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api); 

app.use('*',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , '../dist/VideoPlayer/index.html'));       
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server running on localhost:" + port);
})
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>VideoPlayer</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
    <h1>My First Angular 2 multiline template</h1>
    <p>Second line</p> 
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { VideoCenterComponent } from "./video-center/video-center.component";

const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'videos', component: VideoCenterComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { VideoCenterComponent } from './video-center/video-center.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    VideoCenterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!!!!!

**Issue:** Angular and Express were running on different ports(4200 & 3000). 
I was sending index.html for localhost:3000/api which was not rendering app-root tag inside index.html... while the other api requests api/videos, api/videos/id were fetching data correctly from MongoDB.

**Solution:** As Angular was running on 4200, I am now using localhost:4200 instead and for any /api calls redirecting to localhost:3000.

For this I've added **proxy.conf.json** to my src folder:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Added the declaration in serve in **angular.json**:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "VideoPlayer:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

Run this command:

```
ng serve --proxy-conf src/proxy.conf.json
```

And start your express server as usual.

Read this for more details: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Answer (score 0):

this should be in app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet>

  </router-outlet>
</div>
```

or simply use:

```
templateUrl:'path/to/template.component.html'
```

Comment: Tried that just now again. Isn't working :( Is there a problem with app-routing.ts & app.module.ts?... they look a bit redundant... any error there u can point to?

Comment: Tried moving app-routing.module.ts code to app.module.ts. But that doesn't change anything. Realized either way it's fine. No issue there... but just the simple app-root selector should work. Don't know why that doesn't work.